# How to get psql result in bash?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to get the psql result in bash

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM fictive_table LIMIT 1;' >> /tmp/x.sql
psql --single-transaction -d dbname -f /tmp/x.sql
echo $?
```

This will fail but the result I get in bash is 0. Is there a problem with the logic/code?

From the manual

> psql  returns  0  to  the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal
>   error of its own (out of memory, file not found) occurs

Update:
@Andrea Spadaccini is right. This is not fatal. How can I catch it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the kind of error triggered by the query is not a fatal one like the ones mentioned in the manual, i.e., you don't run out of memory and it does not get a file not found error.

Reading a bit further in the manual, I read that:

> psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1  if a  fatal  error of its own (out of memory, file not found) occurs, 2 if the connection to the server went bad and the        session was not interactive, and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable ON_ERROR_STOP was set.

To catch your error you can try to:

- set the `ON_ERROR_STOP` variable; or,
- change approach, saving the query output to a file and then working with that file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option **`-o`** to write results of a query from psql (the command line terminal) to a file.
[Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3):

```
-o filename
--output=filename

Put all query output into file filename. This is equivalent to the command \o.
```

Answer (score 0):

[I know... this is *old*...]

I discovered that this works for my use case for running psql commands from bash:

```
$ echo "command-to-run" |(sudo -u postgres psql -t -d <dbname> -f -)
```

I'm using psql on my nextcloud server - here's a sample command:

```
$ echo "select uid from oc_users where uid like '%thd%';" |(sudo -u postgres psql -t -d nextcloud -f -)
 bmurphy@thdxxx.xxx
 jostiguy@thdxxx.xxx
 mroth@thdxxx.xxx
 rpatel@thdxxx.xxx
```